# iphone - publish app to app store using application loader

Tags: iphone, app-store, uploading

I've older version of iphone SDK OS 3.1.3 and I created an app using that.
I prepared the app and ready for uploading to app store.
In app store, I created new application and provided all the necessary details. Its now showing "Waiting for upload". As my Mac don't have iPhone SDK OS 3.2 and above, apple's "Application Loader" is not installing.
So, I took my friends help and using his Mac which has latest iOS SDK 4.1 and also "Applicaton Loader" is installed on it. Now I copied the app's zip file to my friend's mac, logged into itunes connect account, started application loader. It says that "No eligible applications were found".
How should I upload my app now?

I can't build my app using latest SDk because, I'm using twitter and facebook libraries which are based on iOS 3.1.3, if i've to download them taht are compatible to iOS 4.1, i've to do all the testing again which can mess my code.

Someone please suggest how to upload my app?

Answer (score 0):

Going to ask a few noddy questions, but they're always worth asking:

- Have you created the new version of your application in Connect? That error normally means that the app loader can't find any application in iTunes connect that is expecting a binary upload.
- Are you sure the application builder isn't using his developer account?

You're also going to hate this advice, but take the plunge and upgrade to 4.1. Yes you'll need to test your applications again, but that's a good thing. In my opinion it's easier to target 4.1 (which represents all future devices and a large portion of installed devices) and ensure it works for older operating systems than it is to fix on an obsolete OS and hope it still works for the latest and greatest.

Comment: Yes, I created new version of application. (I don't have any previous applications in my app store account) This is my first application. Is it necessary to create new application in itunes connect and run application loader on same machine?